# How can I block iOS 10 Notifications

Tags: ios, notifications, firewall, router

It seems that I can not find a solid answer on this. Currently, I've tried this...
Using my NetGear Genie, I went to security and blocked the keywords/domains of:

https://mesu.apple.com

https://appldnld.apple.com

Clicked apply, and nothing happen. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What does "nothing happened" mean? Did you still get push messages?

Comment: Yes, I still received the update notification.

Comment: Please be sure to add the 'solved' info to the Answer and then accept it as soon as the allows.  This will help other people who have a similar problem.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit, please add the solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using NetGear Genie, you must Reboot the router in order for the changes to be applied.

Second, I received an error when trying to add both (**http**) and (**https**) at the same time. I had to reboot with both links being (**http**). then, go back, and add the (**https**).

```
https://mesu.apple.com
https://appldnld.apple.com
appldnld.apple.com
mesu.apple.com
```

This seems to work as of now. Of course, this only works with your home-WIFI. If you were to go connect at someone else's WIFI, you end up with the same problem. So, I found an alternative by installing the [tvOS Beta Profile](https://hikay.github.io/app/NOOTA.mobileconfig), which stops it forever. If you decide to update, just go into **Settings - General - Profile - and then Delete Profile**.

### Steps to install the [tvOS Beta Profile](https://hikay.github.io/app/NOOTA.mobileconfig):

1. Click on the [link](https://hikay.github.io/app/NOOTA.mobileconfig) using your Safari app on your phone.
2. Click Install.
3. Click Install again.
4. Reboot your phone.

You won't be bothered by the recurring notification.

You're only left with a red circle on your settings app. Which doesn't annoy me as much, but if you would like to get rid of that as well, theres another process in which involves using a third party app and turning off your "Find My iPhone".

Article: [How to stop your iPhone from asking to install OS updates](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/08/18/how-to-stop-iphone-asking-to-install-ios-updates/)